# How do I translate Joomla! 3.x System Messages?

Tags: joomla, error-handling, system

I need to translate Joomla 3 system message.

The system would give you error saying: "Invalid field: ...". 
I'm trying to translate the "invalid field: " for other language.

Witch language file and constant name should I look for ?

Thanks

Comment: Well that all depends, which extension are you referring to? `com_users`, `com_content`?

Comment: Hi Lodder. The problem I am getting is with registration form validation.

Comment: Is this for the default Joomla registration or for an extension such as Community Builder etc? There is nothing in the language file for `Invalid field` so I think it's coming from another extension

Comment: It is in com_users in /component/users/?view=registration for example if I don´t fill anything I will get errors "Invalid field: file_name" for all fields. i already look the language file and I can´t find it. I am with Joomla 3.3.1. Anybody knows where can I find all default files from each version ?

Answer (score 1):

Juo have to go to your language folder (e.g.: **language/lt_LT**) and find file **lt_LT.lib_joomla.ini** and input there:

```
JLIB_FORM_FIELD_INVALID="Whatever you want to apear instead of Invalid field"
```